# Lose access to my app on dashboard in Django

Tags: python, django

When I set settings.DEBUG=False, I lose access to my apps in the dashboard except auth and sites. It work fine with settings.DEBUG=True.

```
# Django settings for blog project.
import sys
PROJECT_PATH=r'/home/www/blog'
if not PROJECT_PATH in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0,PROJECT_PATH)


DEBUG =False

TEMPLATE_DEBUG =False 

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '/home/www/blog/database.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'zh-cn'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/www/blog/media/'

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/www/blog/staticDir/'

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/www/blog/static/',
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)


# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'blog.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'blog.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/home/www/blog/templates',
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'article',
    'guestbook',
    'multimedia',
    'archive',
    'about',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

here is an app named article：

```
# coding:utf-8
from markdown import markdown
import datetime

from django.db import models

from django.contrib import admin

VIEWABLE_STATUS = [2,]

class ViewableManager(models.Manager):
    """
        改写 Model.objects 的 get_query_set 方法
        objects 不能接触状态为不可见的 Article 类的实体
    """
    def get_query_set(self):
        default_queryset = super(ViewableManager, self).get_query_set()
        return default_queryset.filter(status__in=VIEWABLE_STATUS)

class Article(models.Model):
    """
        文章类
    """
    STATUS_CHOICES=((1,'Editing'),
                    (2,'Posted'),)
    articleID=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    postDate=models.DateField()
    lastUpdate=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=True)
    keywords=models.CharField(max_length=140,blank=True)
    markdown_content=models.TextField()
    html_content=models.TextField(editable=False)
    status=models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default=1)
    class Meta:
        ordering=['-postDate','-lastUpdate']

    def get_url(self):
        return r'/article/'+str(self.slug)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    def saveCategories(self):
        self.articleCategories.clear()
        categoryList=self.keywords.split()
        for category in categoryList:
            c=Category.objects.filter(label=category)
            if c:
                self.articleCategories.add(c[0])
            else:
                self.articleCategories.create(label=category)                

    def save(self):
        self.html_content=markdown(self.markdown_content)
        self.lastUpdate=datetime.datetime.now()
        super(Article,self).save()
        self.saveCategories()
        print self.html_content
        print self.lastUpdate
        super(Article,self).save()

    admin_objects=models.Manager()
    objects=ViewableManager()

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title',  'status', 'postDate', 'lastUpdate')
    search_fields = ('title', 'keywords','content')
    list_filter = ('status', 'postDate', 'lastUpdate')

admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)

class Category(models.Model):
    label=models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
    masterArticle=models.ManyToManyField(Article,related_name='articleCategories',blank=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "categories" 
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.label
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

And other app named guestbook

```
# coding:utf-8
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from md5 import md5 
from article.models import Article

class guestMessage(models.Model):
    guestName=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    guestEmail=models.EmailField(max_length=75)
    gravatarHash=models.CharField(max_length=33,blank=True)
    content=models.TextField()
    postDate=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    article=models.ForeignKey(Article,blank=True,null=True,
                              related_name='guestMessage')
    def save(self):
        super(guestMessage,self).save()
        self.gravatarHash=(md5(self.guestEmail)).hexdigest()
        super(guestMessage,self).save()    


class guestMessageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('guestName',  'article', 'postDate')
    search_fields = ('guestName', 'article','content')
    list_filter = ('article', 'postDate')

admin.site.register(guestMessage, guestMessageAdmin)
```

here is the urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
urlpatterns += patterns('article.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index'),
    url(r'^article/([\S]+)$', 'articleDetail'),
    url(r'^category/([\S]+)$','articleBYcategory'),
    url(r'^search/$','atricleSearch'),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('guestbook.views',
    url(r'^guestbook/$','guestbook'),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('archive.views',
    url(r'^archive/$','archive'),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('about.views',
    url(r'^about/$','about'),
)
```

www.mysite.com/admin: there is no add or change link . I don't have permission?
pic link: http://img3.douban.com/view/photo/photo/public/p1499852307.jpg

Comment: Show us your dashboard code and settings

Comment: @ilvar thanks for reminding me this.

Comment: Sorry, I've meant django-admin-tools dashboard. Also, I don't see django-admin-tools on your screenshot, just plain Django's admin.

Comment: Is user on screenshot a superuser or just staff?

Comment: With setting.DEBUG=True , everything goes right.

Comment: Sorry.I misunderstand the  "dashboard". I think it is the admin page(www.example.com/admin). It seems the user lose permission when DEBUG=False.

Comment: Permissions are not being checked for the superuser. Could you please show `models` and `admin` for any of broken apps?

Comment: @ilvar hi, *admin* means  the django-admin-module?

Comment: I've meant `admin.py` but I see you moved your admin setup into `models.py` (possible, it's the reason?). Anyway, the only change you are doing is changing `DEBUG` to `False`? Same server, same database, same everything else?

Comment: Same server, same database, same everything else,but the DEBUG.     And the admin is a django module ,a folder with some file, not a single file.

Comment: Then I have no other ideas than move registering admin sites out of `models`. [Official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) say about them residing in separate `admin` module.

Comment: @ilvar  ^_^. It works! Thank you ilvar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no other ideas than move registering admin sites out of `models`. Official docs say about them residing in separate `admin` module.